# Product of functions with mean zero has mean zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $f,g:[0,L] \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a differentiable and periodics function, with period $L>0$.

**Question 1.** If $f$ and $g$ has mean zero, that is,
$$ \int_0^L f(x) \; dx=\int_0^L g(x) \; dx=0$$
then
$$\int_0^L f(x)\cdot g(x) \; dx=0?$$

I know that $f'$ and $g'$ has mean zero, since
$$\int_0^L f'(x) \; dx=f(L)-f(0)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \int_0^L g'(x) \; dx=g(L)-g(0)=0. \tag{1}$$

In this question, the only idea I had was to use the fact $(1)$ and integration by parts, but did not get anything.

**Question 2.** If there exists a differentiable periodic function $\varphi:[0,L] \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $, with period $L>0$, mean zero and derivative $\varphi '$ differentiable , such that
$$\int_0^L \varphi''(x)f(x) \; dx + \int_0^L \varphi'(x) g(x)\; dx=0, $$
then $f$ and $g$ has mean zero?

In the last question, I don't have ideas. But it does not seem to me to be valid in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, consider the case of $f(x) = g(x) = \sin(x)$. Then the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ would be $$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(x)dx = \pi$$

So it doesn't have to equal $0$, meaning that the first statement is not necessarily true.

For the second question, let $f(x) = g(x) = \sin(x)+1$. Let $\phi(x) = \cos(x)-\sin(x)$. The sum of the integrals would then be $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sin\left(x\right)-\cos\left(x\right)\right)\left(\sin\left(x\right)+1\right)dx+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(-\sin\left(x\right)-\cos\left(x\right)\right)\left(\sin\left(x\right)+1\right)dx = 0$$
but the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ of $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ is not $0$, so the second statement is also false.

Answer (score 0):

Another counter example:

$$\int_0^2{(x-1)}{dx} = \int_0^2{(1-x)}dx = 0$$

But:

$$\int_0^2{(x-1)(1-x)}dx = -\int_0^2{(x^2+2x+1)}dx  = -8/3 -4 - 2$$

Comment: But, this functions not are periodics,

Comment: Didn't notice that part.  But they could be extended.